# How do I copy a list of files to a directory?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

When I assign `$(pwd)` to a variable I can't pass it as a path to `cp`:

```
files=$(find /mnt/eee/ttt/*)
pwd 
/mnt/xxx/yyy

path=$(pwd)

echo $path 
mnt xxx yyy
```

when I use path with cp

```
$files | cp $a
cp: target ‘xxx’ is not a directory
```

Comment: strange, why there is no `/` between `mnt xxx yyy`  which is output of echo?

Comment: What is the variable `$a`?

Comment: `cp` doesn't read from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

`cp` doesn't read file names from stdin, so piping the list into `cp` is futile. Did you perhaps confuse `cp` with `cpio`? They are different programs.

You need to run `cp {list of files} {destination directory}`, e.g.

```
cp $files $path
```

If you want to copy all files to the current working directory, you should use `.` for simplicity and readability (`.` denotes the current working directory):

```
cp $files .
```

Be sure to read the `cp` manual page with `man cp` and you'll be a shell wizard in no time :-)

Comment: how would this work? `files+=$(find *)` `newdir=$(mktemp XXXXX -d)` because what I want is `$files | parallel cp {} $newdir` and pass $newdir as a target to the parallel cp command?

Comment: No, you don't cp in parallel. You just copy. You can run `cp $(find ...) /name/of/destination/directory`.

Answer (score -2):

You may be able to use this code:

```
cp $file1 && file2 &&
```